# Stock Research Terminal

Tags: python-3.x, finance

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime



def income_statement(stock):
    number_yrs = input('how many yr(s)?').strip()
    api_key = 'd5abd8f1620e04709eeb05ebafa9af7e'
    IS = requests.get(f'https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/balance-sheet-statement/{stock}?limit={number_yrs}&apikey={api_key}').json()
    IS = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(IS)
    IS = IS.T
    print(IS.T)
    save_to_csv = input('save_to_csv? y or n').strip()
    if save_to_csv == 'y':
            IS.to_csv('IS' + stock + '.csv')

while True:
    command = input('stock?')
    stock = comman.split(' ')[1]
    if comman == 'IS ' + stock:
        income_statement(stock)
        
    elif comman == 'quit':
        break
    else:
        print('Invalid Command.')
```

I am learning python for finance right now. I would like to build a stock research terminal that allows me to call income statement, balance sheet, historical price etc. of a stock from the Internet. I used the above code but when I type IS TSLA, it still gives me the income statement of AAPL. I wonder which parts of the code go wrong? Thanks!

Comment: In your `while` loop, you get your input as `command` and then use the variable `comman`. I'm assuming this is a typo?

Comment: Oops....sorry for the stupid question. Thank you so much!